# LinkedIn Companies endpoint error

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn api and would like to access companies but I'm running into a vague error that I haven't been able to figure out.

I'm using php and the php libracy 'Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn' to access the API. My current application also has the 'rw_company_admin' permission attached to it.

When I make a call to the api endpoint '**/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)**', I get the correct response.

But when I make a call to the '**/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true**' endpoint I get the following error:

"Invalid company query request"

When I perform the exact same query in the LinkedIn Rest Console, I get the response I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after hours of debugging.

The issue will probably be specific to the php package mentioned in the question. The LinkedIn library in use was automatically appending 'format=json' to the query call which sparked an error.

By removing the default output setting in the library, the call worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related to permissions of the application.

If you want to retrieve company list of the user, you should check rw_company_admin permission in the settings page of the application or  give it to scope parameter. Then, you should get a new access token and make requests with it.